# Postgres query pg_views and pg_matviews taking a long time and finally error out

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, catalog-views

We have the following scheduled query which runs every 15 mins.

```
    select schemaname as  schema_name,
           views.viewname view_name,
           views.definition
    from pg_catalog.pg_views views
    where views.schemaname not in ('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
```

most times, the query runs within a second. But several times, it gets stuck for a long time (like 5 mins) and finally exits with an error message similar to

`[2021-11-08 23:52:25] [XX000] ERROR: could not open relation with OID 73677085`

We are using postgres v13 as a data warehouse. There are some queries which drop and recreate about half dozen tables, views and materialized views every hour or so. Is this putting some sort of pressure on pg_catalog tables?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is a performance problem, it is a locking problem.

A query on `pg_views` will block if there is an open transaction that redefines or drops a view. Similarly, a query on `pg_matviews` will block if there is an open transaction that redefines, drops or refreshes a materialized view.

Comment: awesome.. I can use this info..thanks!